# Why doesnt my code provide distinct int values inside a list?

Tags: java

I have a line of code that is supposed to print a list of distinct values, but my current code doesnt provide distinct values.

Student1 is a seperate class from Main, and tutgroupnum is an arraylist created inside the Student1 class containing [1, 9, 9]

My desired output should be [1, 9] but i got [1, 9, 9] instead. Am i interpreting any stream functions wrongly?

```
Stream.of(Student1.tutgroupnum).distinct().forEach(x->System.out.println(x));
```

Comment: If `tutgroupnum` is an `ArrayList`, then use `Student1.tutnumgroup.stream()`, rather than `Stream.of(...)`.

Comment: Your stream contains 1 item which is List

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Don't *explain* what other code is supposedly doing. Build a small complete example that we everybody can look at here. Rest assured: the standard Java APIs all work, your code is doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If `tutgroupnum` is an `ArrayList`, then use `Student1.tutnumgroup.stream()`, rather than `Stream.of(...)`.

The former yields a `Stream<Integer>` (I presume that is the element type in the list).

The latter yields a `Stream<List<Integer>>`, containing a single element, `Student.tutnumgroup`, so the "distinct-ified" version of this stream contains exactly that element too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
tutgroupnum.stream().distinct().forEach(x->System.out.println(x));
```